# PowerShell script to get all octopus environment deployment variables to excel with environment scopes

Tags: azure, powershell, octopus

We are planning to migrate the octopus deployment pipelines to azure Devops pipelines, for this we need to export all the environment octopus variables to excel then i can easily use those variables in azure devops pipelines for deployment

Comment: What do you try so far ?

Comment: Manually collecting the variables and updating inside the excel